# TimeOut Between SSAS (tabular model) et SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have got issues between SSAS and Report Server (SSRS) when I have a large datas in my report (20 000 pages, 800 000 rows).
This is the error log :

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Cannot read the next data row for the dataset 'My DataSet'. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
> The connection either timed out or was lost.
> Impossible de lire les données de la connexion de transport : Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant.
> Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant

Please, can you help me to solve this issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so the error is quite normal, even if you manage to get the result, It is very performance consuming.

you first need to understand what you are up to, and write the report accordingly. 20000 pages with 800000 rows of report cannot be printed, cannot be easily analyzed.

the question is why are you rendering that much data?

If you still insist on getting report then, you should increase

- log in under https://yourssrslink.com/Reports
- open **Site Settings**
- Under General tab, change report timeout value or select `Allow the report to run indefinitely (no timeout)`

Comment: Thanks for your return. We have a many of transaction on one month and the user need to export all information in order to justify activity for auditor.

I changed the report the report timeout but there is also timeout

Comment: try to render it as CSV. As what I say, the report is very very big to be rendered.

Comment: you can give auditor aggregated output. this is what auditor will do by excel :)

Comment: We can't because the auditor wants datas in pdf format :(

Comment: I don't understand because when i restart the SSRS service, the report works (there is memory consumation) fine but after 3 execution it's not working (the isn't memory consumation)

Comment: @DingDing focus on rendering the report as csv. I believe this will solve your problem

Comment: OK, thanks you! How can i modify the rendering in report server portal?

Comment: Easiest is to use URL Access, specifying &rs:command=render&rs:format=csv